# How to I link between two different pages

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I am currently building a two page website. I've linked the navigation menu to all the different sections on the main page with hashtags, for example
`<a href="#services">Services</a>`. So clicking the services link in the navigation menu links to the services section further down on the main page.

However there is one page called Empty Legs that is also in the navigation menu and when I am on the Empty Legs page and want to click services nothing happens. So my question is:

When I am on the Empty Legs page, what do I have to do so that clicking the services link in the navigation menu takes me to the services section on my main page?

I am currently building the website on wordpress.

I hope you understand what I mean and if you have any questions don't hesitate to ask. Any help is appreciated. :)

Comment: well with the link `#service` you using an anchor and it will jump to the element with the `id="service"`. Assuming your main page is called `index.html` as the standard then the link must be `index.html#service`

Answer (score -2):

Instead of `<a href="#services"` you could try `<a href="/#services">`.
This will take you to the homepage and the section `#services`. So it would also work on other pages.

Comment: I'm not sure that you understand the issue here. He uses something that is called `anchor` which is also used to allow the use of pseudoelement `:target` for css. an anchor link can never start with a slash which will look for a `folder` then with then name `#service` which is a competely different outcome.